# Printwriter to write into a file

Tags: java

Why can't I write a big amount of data via PrintWriter?

```
String result = acquireLengthyData();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("D:/log.txt");
out.println(result);
```

where `result.lenght() = 189718`. But some data were missing in `log.txt`. Why? How can I write to the file correctly?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @Powerslave I've written that _some data were missing in log.txt_. There is no any error.

Comment: Are you sure that it's missing data at the end, and it's not that `result` isn't being formed incorrectly?

Comment: @Yann4 Of course. I ran the code in a debug-mode and the end of the string differs from that there is in the file.

Comment: If you were closing your resources properly (which [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) makes easy) you wouldn't have run into this issue.  Always close files/connections/etc. when you're done with them, or you could be left in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @St.Antario Actually you need to `flush` I think. UPDATE: Ah, I see someone hinted the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Class PrintWriter
```

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

So you need to enable the `automatic flush` option while creating the Printwriter:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:/log.txt"),true);
out.println(result);
// finally{out.close();} with a null check, if required.
```

**Note**: Enabling auto flush will force the contents in the buffer to be written to the output stream, even if the buffer has not reached its content holding capacity.

Answer (score 5):

You need to flush after write, it flushes the stream. `PrintWriter#flush` would do that.

> Flushes the stream. If the stream has saved any
>   characters from the various write() methods in a buffer, write them
>   immediately to their intended destination.

`PrintWriter#flush` - [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush())

*Code Snippet* -

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("D:/log.txt");
out.println(result);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

And do not forget to close the writer after use.

Comment: Wait - is `flush()` strictly required even when calling `close()`?

Comment: Put a glance on Api - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintWriter.java#PrintWriter.close%28%29 It answers alot & Yes `close` method of `FileWriter` does but specifically for `PrintWriter`  does not flush.

Comment: Are you seriously? I asked what that method does in a nutshell.

Comment: @St.Antario - *Flushes the stream.  If the stream has saved any characters from the various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their intended destination.* - from javadoc

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder - But shouldn't closing implicitly flush the data?

Comment: And to avoid confusion - the second sentence in TheLostMinds comment is the definition of "flushing the stream". @SubhrajyotiMajumder - I would make that information part of the answer.